# Codename one issue devilering binary for iOS

Tags: ios, codenameone, release, application-loader

I've just attempted to upload a release build of a Codename One app to iTunes connect using Application loaded and hit this new error;

[image: Screenshot of error from application loader]

*note: the blacked out parts are just the application name*

The app does use the barcode scanning library so likely should include the mentioned library (libzbar) however it seems to be in the incorrect location in the ipa package.
This app has had the barcode scanning library from the start and we've never seen this before.

**Edit:**
Here's the content of the src folder in the project;

[image: content of src folder]

and here is native/ios;

[image: content of native/ios folder]

*note: I've blacked out some identifying file names*

The file in question does exist in the lib/impl/native/ios folder. But looking at our project history in git I can see this is not a new addition, it's been there since the branch was first created in 2016.

**Edit 2:**
The content of my codenameone_settings.properties file;

```
1.arg.rim.obfuscation=false
baseClass=src/generated/StateMachineBase.java
codename1.android.keystore=*********.ks
codename1.android.keystoreAlias=*********
codename1.android.keystorePassword=*********
codename1.arg.android.captureRecord=false
codename1.arg.android.debug=false
codename1.arg.android.enableProguard=false
codename1.arg.android.facebook_permissions="user_about_me", "email"
codename1.arg.android.gradle=true
codename1.arg.android.newPeer=true
codename1.arg.android.playService.maps=true
codename1.arg.android.proguardKeep=\  -keep class net.sourceforge.zbar.** {*;} 
codename1.arg.android.release=true
codename1.arg.android.targetSDKVersion=23
codename1.arg.android.versionCode=*********
codename1.arg.android.xapplication=<activity android\:name\="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity" android\:screenOrientation\="landscape"/> <meta-data android\:name\="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android\:value\="*********"/>
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/><uses-feature         android\:glEsVersion\="0x00020000"         android\:required\="true"/><uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/><uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <uses-permission android\:name\="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/><uses-feature         android\:glEsVersion\="0x00020000"         android\:required\="true"/><uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.CAMERA"/><uses-feature android\:name\="android.hardware.camera" android\:required\="false"/>
codename1.arg.build.incSources=1
codename1.arg.build.version=*********
codename1.arg.facebook.appId=*********
codename1.arg.ios.add_libs=libc++.dylib;libicucore.dylib;libz.dylib;CoreData.framework;CoreText.framework;GLKit.framework;ImageIO.framework;SystemConfiguration.framework;CoreData.framework;CoreTelephony.framework;SystemConfiguration.framework;AdSupport.framework;
codename1.arg.ios.afterFinishLaunching=[GMSServices provideAPIKey\:@"*********"];
codename1.arg.ios.application_exits=false
codename1.arg.ios.bundleVersion=3.76
codename1.arg.ios.dsym=false
codename1.arg.ios.glAppDelegateHeader=\#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"\n\#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"
codename1.arg.ios.includePush=true
codename1.arg.ios.includePushEnt=false
codename1.arg.ios.interface_orientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait\:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
codename1.arg.ios.locationUsageDescription=*********
codename1.arg.ios.newStorageLocation=true
codename1.arg.ios.objC=true
codename1.arg.ios.plistInject=<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSExceptionDomains</key><dict><key>*********</key><dict><key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key><true/><key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key><true/></dict><key>*********</key><dict><key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key><true/></dict></dict></dict>
codename1.arg.ios.pods=,GoogleMaps
codename1.arg.ios.pods.platform=7.0,7.0
codename1.arg.ios.pods.sources=,https\://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon=false
codename1.arg.ios.project_type=ios
codename1.arg.ios.statusbar_hidden=false
codename1.arg.ios.testFlight=false
codename1.arg.j2me.nativeThemeConst=0
codename1.arg.java.version=8
codename1.arg.rim.obfuscation=false
codename1.arg.win.ver=8
codename1.description=
codename1.displayName=*********
codename1.icon=icon.png
codename1.ios.appid=*********
codename1.ios.certificate=
codename1.ios.certificatePassword=
codename1.ios.debug.certificate=*********.p12
codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword=*********
codename1.ios.debug.provision=*********.mobileprovision
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.ios.release.certificate=*********.p12
codename1.ios.release.certificatePassword=*********
codename1.ios.release.provision=*********.mobileprovision
codename1.j2me.nativeTheme=nbproject/nativej2me.res
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.mainName=*********
codename1.packageName=*********
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
codename1.secondaryTitle=CodenameOne_Template
codename1.vendor=*********
codename1.version=3.7
guiResource=*********.res
mainForm=Main
package=generated
releaseVersion=3.7
userClass=src/userclasses/StateMachine.java
userClassAbs=*********StateMachine.java
```

**Edit 3:**
This issue is caused by an extra entry in Copy Bundle Resources which is adding the entire projectname-src folder into the bundle including all resources already copied and all libraries.
Here's a screenshot from XCode with a project source downloaded from the CodeName One build server;

[image: xcode build phase with erroneous step]

**For now it seems the work-around is to download the project source and build and submit it from XCode on a mac.**

note make sure to also take the following steps;

- select the correct team for signing the app
- set the target to iOS 8
- add an app store icon to the app icon xcassets file (1024*1024)
- active the push capabilities if you app uses push
- add the following to the info section (plist);
- Privacy - Camera Usage Description
- Privacy - Media Library Usage Description
- Privacy - Microphone Usage Description
- Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
- **Remove "{project name}-src" from Build Phases>Copy Bundle Resources**

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the files in your src/* hierarchy in the project? Also the list of files under `native/ios` would be helpful.
You didn't copy any files into the src hierarchy right?

Comment: I've added that to my post

Comment: OK this looks like the right location for that file. Did you ever submit a binary of this app to the appstore in the past? What's the version of the Application Loader and Mac OS? In the past we had weird issues like this due to older application loader versions.

Comment: Yes definitely uploaded numerous builds of this project for test-flight as well as a handful have gone live on iTunes.  
Application loader version is 3.7, which likely was updated with xcode, a week or two ago. I don't think I've submitted any other builds successful since then.

Comment: EDIT: I just tried on another mac which still has 3.6 and it gave the same error

Comment: I have application loader 3.7 so I would suggest checking for an update. I'll try to reproduce this on our side with a test and see if this is a regression

Comment: As I mentioned I did try on the latest version of application loader (3.7) *as well* as 3.6.
Both are showing this issue even though this was working as recently as a week and a half ago.

Comment: I had some issues yesterday and didn't get around to test this yet. I'll try to reproduce this on our side.

Comment: I just tried this with the zbar cn1lib and wasn't able to reproduce the issue. What's in your `codenameone_settings.properties`?

Comment: Hi Shai, I've just realized I'm actually using this library;  
https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner  
  
Not too sure if that makes any difference or not.  
I've updated the post to include my settings.properties file.  
  
I also experimented with a build on Codename One 3.6 but that failed with 3 extra additional versions of the same error for these libaries as well;  
libFBSDKLoginKit.a, libFBSDKCoreKit.a, and libFBSDKShareKit.a  
   
it's looking more and more like apple has changed their system in some way

Comment: It seems like this is related to the little monkey QR scanner. I was under the wrong impression that this library only added Android support on top of the existing code scanner lib but it seems this isn't the case. Which cn1libs do you have exactly? I see maps but do you have both qr scanning libs? They might be exclusive to one another now

Comment: I've just tried a build with the standard QR scanning library and it had the same error when trying to upload.  
I've now looked at the source for ios and noticed that in Build Phases under Copy Bundle Resources there is a list of all the required resources as well as an entire copy of the src folder.  

Removing this seems to have fixed the issue

Comment: We don't do that, when I built this didn't happen and I was able to upload. If you can isolate why this was generated that would help

Comment: I sent the build with source and I opened the ios project from the source and this phase is there in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.    
I can't isolate it any further than that.  

I can confirm that a project source from around a month ago (30/10/17) Did not have this step in the Copy Bundle Resources step.

I've added another screenshot to my post.

Comment: Just so we are clear, you are using the binary built by the server when uploading not xcode right?

Comment: I've tried both they both produce the same error

Answer (score 1):

We found something that's misbehaving but it's unclear why that happened. The error is a bit different than the one you are getting and we don't see the src include stuff like you see it. However, it might be the reason for this.

We will try to push it out with the coming update this Friday (November 24th 2017).

Comment: I just tried to send another build today and I'm still seeing this issue

Comment: Are you sending a versioned build?

Comment: If you mean which version of Codename one, this was using the 'Latest' option

Comment: In the build hints I see above it's configured to 3.7 not latest

Comment: I assure you I sent and tried a build using 'latest'

Comment: OK, just making sure. I asked Steve on this but I suggest filing an issue so this doesn't get lost. If you can reproduce this issue with a standalone project that would help in addressing it.